# How to get console changes as notifications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using rails3. I have an  requirement like when I create a user from rails console at my browser I get a notification like user created if I open user user with name opened.

How i get this. Please give me any ideas.

Thanks in advance and response is very appreciable

Comment: If you want a real-time connection, you should look into web sockets (Node.JS & Socket.io are good at it). The other option is to "fake" the real-time refresh with an Ajax request sent every X seconds that will check if there is new stuff, and if yes, render it.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a boolean column in your users model called, say: "already_seen?"

When you open the user in a view you can do

```
<% unless @user.already_seen? %>
This user has been created recently
<% @user.update_attribute(already_seen?: true) %>
<% end %>
```